# Cambiar eje de coordenadas de un FrameLayout (solo código)

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo un `Framelayout` y le pego elementos (otros Framelayout) solo a través de código y le doy las posiciones con las funciones `setX` y `setY`, y el eje de coordenadas empieza en la esquina superior izquierda (0,1).

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el eje de coordenadas al que yo quiera? Por ejemplo que el eje de coordenadas empiece en la esquina inferior izquierda (0,0) ó en le esquina inferior derecha (1,0) o en el centro (0.5,0.5)o en cualquier otro lugar dentro del FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo más aproximado sería usar [Gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) por ejemplo, para posicionar la vista en la esquina superior izquierda:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) video.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
myFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Para las coordenadas que indicas sería:

**(0,0)**

```
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
```

**(0,1)**

```
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.RIGHT;
```

**(0.5,0.5)**

```
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

**(1,0)**

```
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

**(1,1)**

```
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.RIGHT;
```